# How to create a tooltip over cell in Struts2 display:column?

Tags: struts2

I have a long text to display in a struts2 display:column. Thus, I truncate since it's not that important. How do I decorate each of those cells with a regular html tooltip (title/alt) when the cursor is positioned over that cell? This way I could still display the complete text to the user on demand.

Could I extend the display:column tag?

```
<display:column sortable="true" property="codeIdentification"  />
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used a table decorator, which encapsulates the text (codeIdentification) with a span and an title attribute. i.e.

```
<span title="xxx">codeIdentification</span>
```

Sufficient.

You may define the decorator in the display:column tag.

```
<display:table name="dataPage" id="process" export="false" 
               decorator="com.mysite.decorator.CodeStringFormatter" 
               requestURI="dataList.action"
               sort="list"
               pagesize="30"
               >
```

Of course, in this decorator class you need to create a getter method. In my case that is getCodeIdentificatin()

That does the job. Sufficient.